# How to match columns in a pandas dataframe and print a certain row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

Iam trying to match a row value in a column after a user inputs a value that matches one value in a row. Then produces some statistics. Ex a user inputs flight orgin state 'il' city 'chicago' dest city'la' state'CA'. Your are flying from chicago airport code ORD to La airport code LAX. The distance is 2000 miles and approimate time is 3.25 hours. The best airline based on time is American Airline(AA).You are flying from chicago il airport code ORD to la airport code LAX. The distance is 2000 miles. The fastest flight time is 2 hours using airline AA.

```
FlightDate  DayOfWeek   UniqueCarrier   Origin  OriginCityName  OriginState Dest    DestCityName    DestState   Route   DepTime ArrTime Delayed TaxiOut TaxiIn  DelayLength SchedDuration   ActualDuration  AirTime Distance
12/1/2017   Friday  B6  ATL Atlanta  GA BOS Boston  MA  ATL<-->BOS  948 1214    0   23  3   -26 165 146 120 946
12/1/2017   Friday  B6  ATL Atlanta  GA BOS Boston  MA  ATL<-->BOS  1208    1436    0   11  7   -26 166 148 130 946


OriginState = input('enter origin state ')
OriginCity = input('enter origin city ')
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    if r['OriginState'] == OriginState and r['OriginCityName'] == OriginCity:
        originplace = r['Origin']
    else:
        pass
DestState = input('enter destination state ')
DestCity = input('enter destination city ')
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['DestState'] == DestState and row['DestCityName'] == DestCity:
        DestPlace = row['Dest']
    else:
        pass
print('You are flying from',OriginState,'airport code',originplace,'to',DestCity,'airport code',DestPlace,'.')
```

Comment: You should avoid iterating over a dataframe as it is highly inefficient. You could filter the data by using a boolean mask. For example, `df[(df.OriginState == OriginState) & (df.OriginCity == OriginCity)]` will give you a subset of the `df` with the specified origin state and origin city that the user specifies.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the flights from origin to destination using:
`df_custom= df[(df['OriginState'] == OriginState) & ( df['OriginCityName'] == OriginCity) & (df['DestState'] == DestState) & (df['DestCityName'] == DestCity)]`

Then use `df_custom` to get the best flight with shortest duration.

Comment: You should change your code to `df_custom= df[(df['OriginState'] == OriginState) & ( df['OriginCityName'] == OriginCity) & (df['DestState'] == DestState) & (df['DestCityName'] == DestCity)]`.